# How can I extract all 4-digit numbers from a php text?

Tags: php, regex

for example : I had a text `testt1591fff44f43f0015ffef159` given that there won't be more than 4 consecutive number in that string, how can I extract 1591 and 0015 out of it by PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

```
<?php
$text = 'testt1591fff44f43f0015ffef159';

preg_match_all('~\d{4}~',  $text, $matches);

?>
```

Didnot test the code

Comment: The `[…]` are not required as `\d` already is a character class.

Comment: Changed the answer, I always use 0-9 so that is why I used []